# Passing line numbers from external command to run macro

Tags: vim

I've seen a couple of questions about passing line numbers from Vim to an external command, but I want to do the opposite. I want to run a file through jshint and then apply corrections to each line number based on the jshint output.

For example, I'm trying to append a semicolon on each line that is missing one. Right now I'm shelling out to jshint and parsing the output but I'm not sure how I can use that to run a macro on multiple lines.

My current thought right now is to:

- call jshint and parse out the line numbers for "Missing semicolon" errors
- iterate through line numbers
- for each line number, run `G<LINE_NUMBER>A;`

Here is what I have so far for parsing the jshint output:

`:r ! jshint % | grep 'Missing semicolon' | awk '{ print $3 }' | sed 's/,//'`

Is there a convenient way for me to do something like `xargs` in Vim or to parse the output of the external command into an array that I can loop over?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's see.  You might try using `errorformat`:

```
let lines = split(system('jshint --verbose ' . shellescape(expand('%', 1))), "\n", 1)
let &errorformat = '%f: line %l\, col %v\, %m'
cgetexpr lines
for line in uniq(sort(map(filter(getqflist(), 'v:val["valid"] && v:val["text"] =~# "\\m^Missing semicolon"'), 'v:val["lnum"]')))
    execute line . 's/$/;/'
endfor
```

Not what I'd call "convenient", but what do I know.

Then it might occur to you that the missing semicolons might not always be at end of lines.  So you'd modify the code like this:

```
function! Cmp(a, b)
    return a:a[0] == a:b[0] ? a:b[1] - a:a[1] : a:b[0] - a:a[0]
endfunction

let lines = split(system('jshint --verbose ' . shellescape(expand('%', 1))), "\n", 1)
let &errorformat = '%f: line %l\, col %v\, %m'
cgetexpr lines
for p in uniq(sort(map(filter(getqflist(), 'v:val["valid"] && v:val["text"] =~# "\\m^Missing semicolon"'),
        \ '[str2nr(v:val["lnum"]), str2nr(v:val["col"])]'), 'Cmp'))
    let line = getline(p[0])
    call setline(p[0], line[ : p[1]-2] . ';' . line[p[1]-1 :])
endfor
```

Then it may occur to you that this doesn't handle the case of tabs.  That's a problem because by default JSHint's idea of a tab is tab stop = 4, while Vim's is tab stop = 8.  Then you... might fix that as an exercise, or you might come to your senses and use a real JavaScript parser to fix this instead of Vim. :)